# Kali linux: public key not available

Tags: apt, kali-linux

When I run apt-get update I get this error

```
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F6BC817356A3D45E
```

I can see for ubuntu [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943539/the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-avai) worked. I have not tried it because I am still abit afraid of doing something wrong.

I tried to search for "keyserver kali linux" and such, but nothing fit my problem except the one regarding ubuntu. Therefore I do want to try the command from [the ubuntu forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943539/the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-avai).

I would also appreciate if an explenation on why it is a given that xxx keyserver is used and how I would have gone about figuring which keyserver is for my distro.

Comment: The instructions on how to install the kali key should be on the kali website. Installing the ubuntu key won't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command to add the missing key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys F6BC817356A3D45E
```

Comment: What does the ubuntu key server have anything to do with kali? Arent they two different distros? And Cinaed Simons said that adding this key wouldnt help as it is for ubuntu.

Comment: @MrKrisey You have added a third party repository to Kali Linux which require a pub key. Cinaed Simons is totally right because adding others repository may break your configuration. This answer come to solve only the missing key issue, you can add some details to your question, I will submit an edit (the repository name recently added).

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution after cleaning off the old keys:

```
wget https://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/kali-archive-keyring/kali-archive-keyring_{distro release year}_all.deb
apt install ./kali-archive-keyring_{distro release year}_all.deb
```

Go to the archive website to check/confirm that your distro release year is available. Else, track an archive repository and find the keyring package listed there to add that key using that address e.g. old.kali.org/kali

Then, run

```
apt update
```

to ensure that everything is working.

These steps were first sited [here](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?38858-apt-get-update-GPG-error-key-expired).

***NB:** Thanks all for sighting the difference between Ubuntu and Kali keyrings and thus the packages that will be downloaded. Especially, Ubuntu is not Debian under the hood but Kali is! You could face many issues if you do not tread carefully on these paths.*